# Jqgrid selecting multiple rows after cancel edit

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing, jqgrid-formatter

im facing an issue with jqgrid , Please Go to Row Editing(new) >Inline Navigator(new) in the link [jqgrid inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

step1: Click on add Row( a row is added in edit mode).
step2: without saving click on any other row .
step 3: the edit mode disappears (which is correct) and the row which was clicked gets selected.
step4: click on any other row except the select row , that gets selected tooo!!!!!! (even though multiselect is off).

**how can i solve this issue, i want to unselect all other rows in jqgrid if a row is selected**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same issue that I reported here: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/728

You should be able to fix it by upgrading your jqGrid version.